# Datastore Entities not showing

Tags: android, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-endpoints

> https://cloud.google.com/developers/articles/how-to-build-mobile-app-with-app-engine-backend-tutorial/

Almost halfway down this webpage at heading "Test Client and Backend Communication", at Step 8: when i visit localhost:8888/_ah/admin/

i am not seeing any entity in the dropdown (this is my third try to this tutorial. At first two tries i would only see one entity 'MessageData' out of three.) I should see three entities, esp. CheckIn.

I am stumped. Plus, i am in the learning phase. What must i do in order to create an entity in the datastore?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the code for the MainActivity:
https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/solutions-mobile-shopping-assistant-backend-java/blob/master/MobileAssistant-Tutorial/Phase1_Snippets/MainActivity.01.java

You have first to generate the Cloud EndPoint Library.
Then, you have to check if you have this lign on AndroidManifest.xml:

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

The first classe you run when you launch an android app is define here:

```
 <application           
        android:allowBackup="true" 
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher" 
        android:label="@string/app_name" 
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

         <!-- Notre activité SplashScreen -->
         <activity android:label="@string/app_name" android:name="com.example.test.MainActivity">
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
                </intent-filter>
         </activity>
</application>
```

Hope that help you !